# How to change xsd schema import in Jax-WS RI exposed service wsdl?

Tags: soap, xsd, wsdl, schema, jax-ws

I have a problem with my JAX-WS RI Soap service. Doing a "?wsdl" request against my service endpoint exposes the service wsdl. But all the external xsd schemata are referenced with an absolut url. The Problem now is, that this url isn't reachable from outside the webcenter, cause the host is the webcenter internal server ip.

```
<xsd:schema><xsd:import namespace="http://xmldefs.myhostadress.com/Spec" schemaLocation="http://173.45.9.212:10391/Service/SpecService?xsd=1"/></xsd:schema>
```

Is it possible to configure Jax-WS to render relative paths in the wsdl?

Greetings, 
smoothny

Answer (score 0):

You basically need WSLD customization [WSLD customization](https://jax-ws.java.net/nonav/2.1.2/docs/customizations.html). In particular, [XSD Customization](https://jax-ws.java.net/nonav/2.1.2/docs/customizations.html#2.9_XML_schema_customization). Also more details here [JAXB customization](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs103/webserv/data_types.html).

Comment: but the wsimport tool is not involved in the wsdl generation jaxws is doing while application runtime, is it?

Comment: Yes you are right. Sorry. wsimport is to generate java artifacts from WSLD. In your case it's wsgen which generates WSDL from java.

Comment: because I have to tell my tomcat application server to generate the wsdl with relative paths or inline schemas, if I do the "?wsdl" call to my soap service.